# Meteor collection.update foreach using data from the documents to update

Tags: mongodb, meteor, foreach

I'm learning Meteor (I'm a noob though), and would like to update multiple records in a collection based on the change of one variable.

There are 15 documents in the collection, each have 2 fix values (call it data1 and data2), data3 that is a variable that is periodically changing, and many other fields calculated based on these three parameters.

I know the syntax is terrible, I'd just like to show what I'd like to achieve:

```
Collection.update(
{data1: 158000},
{
data1: 158000,
data2: 0.25,
data3: variable1,
data4: variable1 - data1,
data5: data4*data2
etc...}

Collection.update(
{data1: 200000},
{
data1: 200000,
data2: 0.5,
data3: variable1,
data4: variable1 - data1,
data5: data4*data2
etc...}

etc...
```

So basically I'd like to have an update function for each document in the collection, and I need to be able to calculate the values to update to based on the data in each collection and one variable passed to the whole function. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For demonstration purposes, create a sample collection set for testing:

```
db.collection.insert([
    { "data1": 158000, "data2": 0.25 },
    { "data1": 200000, "data2": 0.5 },
    { "data1": 208000, "data2": 0.75 }
]);
```

Create a list of objects that have the update query and derived objects that you want to update based on the query:

```
var queryList = [
        { "data1": 158000, "data2": 0.25 },
        { "data1": 200000, "data2": 0.5 },
        { "data1": 208000, "data2": 0.75 }
    ],
    updateList = [],
    query = {},
    obj = {},
    update = { "$set": {} },        
    variable1 = 300000;
```

If you would like to query every document and you don't know the keys beforehand, you can generate the `updateList` array dynamically by using the `Collection.find()` cursor and iterate over the cursor using `forEach` method like:

```
var queryList = [];
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc){
    var obj = {};
    obj["data1"] = doc.data1;
    obj["data2"] = doc.data2;
    queryList.push(obj);
});
```

Next step is to iterate over the query list array using `forEach` and do the update using the `$set` operator:

```
queryList.forEach(function (item){
    obj["data1"] = item["data1"];
    obj["data2"] = item["data2"];
    obj["data3"] = variable1;
    obj["data4"] = variable1 - item["data1"];
    obj["data5"] = obj["data4"] * item["data2"];

    query["data1"] = item["data1"];
    update["$set"] = obj;

    db.collection.update(query, update);
});
```

Finally query for all the documents in the collection to show the update:

```
db.collection.find();
```

**Result**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5530d9f0180e849972938fd7"),
    "data1" : 158000,
    "data2" : 0.25,
    "data3" : 300000,
    "data4" : 142000,
    "data5" : 35500
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5530d9f0180e849972938fd8"),
    "data1" : 200000,
    "data2" : 0.5,
    "data3" : 300000,
    "data4" : 100000,
    "data5" : 50000
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5530d9f0180e849972938fd9"),
    "data1" : 208000,
    "data2" : 0.75,
    "data3" : 300000,
    "data4" : 92000,
    "data5" : 69000
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The solution above was working perfectly after slight modifications I needed. Thanks a lot for taking the time and helping me.

Comment: @balu000 No worries :-)